# Duplicate row in database with Unique key constraint

Tags: mysql, database, duplicates

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `some_table` (
  `ReferenceId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ten` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `so` bigint(18) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mc` bigint(18) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ev` bigint(18) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sclso` bigint(18) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sowbse` bigint(18) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AsOfDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `dud` date NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `ReferenceId` (`ReferenceId`,`AsOfDate`),
  KEY `fk_main_table` (`ReferenceId`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_main_table` FOREIGN KEY (`ReferenceId`) REFERENCES `some_other_table` (`Id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

In this table I have added a multiple column `UNIQUE` index on columns `ReferenceId` and `AsOfDate`. But I just noticed that there is a duplicate entry in the table even when we have this constraint.

[image]

Check the 2 highlighted records. The constraint is applied on first and second-last columns, which are identical but should not have existed.

What could be the possible issues? The data in this table is not inserted/updated from any web/desktop application but only from 1 script that runs in background.

Edit: I have only identified this 1 index being duplicate and the script have been running for past 3 months.

Comment: What do you mean when you say the name of columns is changed?

Comment: Could you add results of SHOW CREATE TABLE or SHOW INDEX IN for your table?

Comment: Can you insert query instead of image?

Comment: Can you pls provide some examples of the data being the same? Isn't it the case of having multiple records where let's say the rererence id is set and the as of date is null? Because this is the documented behaviour.

Comment: to clarify, when you say you get duplicate rows, you mean all the rows that are duplicate have the same ReferenceID AND the same AsOfDate value, right ? Because thats the definition of your unique key. I sense there is a confusion on your part with the constraint name "ReferenceId" and the constraint definition  ("ReferenceID", "AsOfDate").

Comment: I have edited my post with clarifications.

Comment: Have you added the unique index later to the table after these records had been inserted?

Comment: Also, how did you create the output? Was it a simple `select * from table` query?

Comment: @Shadow, the index was present since the day I created the table. And yes, it was simple `SELECT * FROM table`.

Comment: Also, no member of the team was aware of this until a BI developer tried copying the table schema and data for her work. So I have no idea as to how and when this happened.

Comment: There could be 2 obvious explanations, but I'm not sure if any of them apply here: 1) You just think that there is a unique index on those columns, you are getting the table definition from one table, and the data from another one. 2) The two values in the two records only seem to be the same, but in reality, they are different. When exported as text, the differences disappear. Unfortunately, I cannot explain this with integer and date fields. The not so obvious explanation is that you found a bug in mysql.

Comment: What version on MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Either one of two things is true:

- You're mistaken
- Your database is corrupt

To verify your assertion, write a query to show only the invalid condition:

```
select count(*) as N, ReferenceId, AsOfDate
from some_table
group by ReferenceId, AsOfDate
having count(*) > 1
```

(You can dispense with the unnecessary, nonstandard backtick-quotes, by the way.  You'll find it makes SQL more pleasant to deal with.)

If that query produces any rows, your database is corrupt, by definition: the table cannot be declared unique on two columns and admit two rows of the same values.  Find out what's wrong, and fix it.

If it doesn't produce any rows, it *might* still be corrupt, but that's evidence you're mistaken.  You'll want to re-check your facts, and see if there's another explanation for what you're seeing.  Get your hands on the verbatim SQL that produced that output (or is supposed to have done).  Execute it, redirecting the output to a temporary table or file, and verify the duplication.  If you don't find it, it's not there.  If you do, see "corruption" in your friendly manual.

One last thing, just as an aside.  This line:

```
  KEY `fk_main_table` (`ReferenceId`),
```

is likely not doing you much good.  You already have

```
  UNIQUE KEY `ReferenceId` (`ReferenceId`,`AsOfDate`),
```

and your DBMS probably creates an index to enforce that, and probably uses that index to locate rows by ReferenceId.